# Bedeutung von "biedere Haut"

Tags: meaning

> Ebensowenig gelang es mir, noch einmal mit dem fürchterlichen Reddinger zu sprechen, und so kam mir diese **biedere Haut**, die noch ganz auf das Faustrecht eingeschworen war, für immer aus dem Blick
>
> So sagte Harald einmal: „Pachnitzki ist eine **biedere Haut**. Auf seine Eulen bin ich sehr gespannt. Wir werden sie morgen früh beim Rundgang durch das Schloß wohl zu sehen bekommen. Ohne diese Vögel müßte der alte Mann sich hier so allein auch zu Tode langweilen.

Dies sind die einzigen Beispiele, die im Netz zu finden sind. Mein Bauchgefühl sagt mir, **dass es sich bloß um ein biederes oder gutes Gemüt handelt**. Doch das kann ich mir aus den oben aufgeführten Beispielen nicht erschließen. Liege ich richtig? Und warum kommt der Ausdruck so selten vor? ([eine Recherche bei Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biedere%20Haut&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) ergibt keine Treffer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Haut](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH04470#XGH04470)

Zusätzlich zur Beschreibung der äußeren Hülle eines Lebewesens, einer Frucht oder auch eines Gegenstandes wird Haut schon lange auch im übertragenen Sinn verwendet.

So kann mit "Haut" nicht nur seine Hülle, sondern auch der ganze Mensch gemeint sein. Ursprünglich wurden nur Menschen mit schlechtem Charakter als "Haut" bezeichnet, mit einem positiven Adjektiv kommt später aber die entsprechende auch positive Eigenschaft dazu:

> Eine ehrliche Haut
> Eine biedere Haut (*bieder* war ein Synonym zu *ehrlich, rechtschaffen*)

Frühes Beispiel aus dem Mittelhochdeutschen:

> *Daʒ er sî mit der Hant sluoc*
> *alsô daʒ die Guote*
> *vil sêre bluote.*
> *Er sprach: ir eʒʒent, übel **hût**!*

Answer (score 5):

Duden führt unter Punkt 4 von *Haut* auf:

> (umgangssprachlich; in Verbindung mit bestimmten, meist positiv charakterisierenden attributiven Adjektiven) Mensch, Person

Halbwegs gebräuchlich ist noch *ehrliche Haut*, für *bieder* kann man sich etwas aus dem Angebot heraussuchen, je nachdem eher der zuverlässige oder einfältige Aspekt betont werden soll.